# How can I trim a prefix string in an Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column whose values consist of a prefix and then some value, e.g.:

```
ABC-Car
ABC-Dog
ABC-Suit
CBR-Train
```

In my query I would like to trim off certain prefixes, e.g. if I trimmed off 'ABC-' it would give me the following:

```
Car
Dog
Suit
CBR-Train
```

The only problem is, all characters are valid for the part after the prefix.  So it's possible I could have:

```
ABC-ABC-Cat
```

I want this trimmed value to return:

```
ABC-Cat
```

The TRIM and LTRIM functions appear to use pattern/character matching rather than once-only string matching.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want with either of these functions or with another built-in function?

Currently I'm thinking I'll have to use a CASE statement to check for that prefix at the beginning of each value and if it exists, SUBSTR it off, else return the column unchanged.  Hoping there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regexp_replace` is what you'll want to use for this.

Usage examples:

```
select regexp_replace('ABC-Car', 'ABC-(.*)','\1') from dual; --returns 'Car'
select regexp_replace('ABC-ABC-Car', 'ABC-(.*)','\1') from dual; --returns 'ABC-Car'
select regexp_replace('ABC-ABC-Car', 'ABC-(.*)','\1') from dual; --returns 'CBR-Train'
```

Comment: Be aware that regex functions are 10g+.

Comment: @Ponies, it sometimes feels like you're following me around: you make it to all the SQL questions.  :) +1